# Google Sheets Custom Number Format - Unchanging #<1000

Tags: google-sheets, text-formatting, google-sheets-cell-format

I am well aware of the excellent Custom Number Formula:

```
[<999950]0.0,"K";[<999950000]0.0,,"M";0.0,,,"B"
```

Which abbreviates #**,000** numbers to #**K**, #**,000,000** to #**M** etc...

However, I am looking for a formula that will leave numbers **below 1000 unchanged**.

For example, the number 999 will remain 999 but the number 1,001 will abbreviate to 1K.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **custom number format:** **`[<1000]0"";[<1000000]0,"K"`**

  [image: 0]

Comment: the only question is... how can i add the `[<1000]0"";` to the existing formula `[<999950]0.0,"K";[<999950000]0.0,,"M";0.0,,,"B"` to give a complete solution?

Comment: I tried `[<1000]0"";[<100000]0.0,"K";[<999950000]0.0,,"M";0.0,,,"B"` but for some reason I don't understand it doesn't work :-(

Comment: that won't do, this is the only way how you can have this working `[<1000]0"";[<1000000]0,"K"` custom internal formattings are not so flexible